# i'am have trouble to display my data. I can display data with a specific id. but i don't know how to display data with different id on the same page

Tags: php, html, sql

the SQL that i use to get data from data base

```
<?php 
require 'functions.php';

$pesanan = query("SELECT order_name, order_quantity,table_id FROM `pesanan` WHERE transaction_id  = 20;");
?>
```

the loop i can show the data but, it is only for data with transaction_id = 20

```
<?php include("temp_sidebar.php");?>
      <div class="header">
          <h3 class="text-center">Order List</h3>
      </div>
    <div class="container-two border border-white border-3">
    
        <div class="order_card">
          <h4 style="text-align: center" >
          <span class="border-bottom border-white border-3">Order 1</span>
          </h4>
          
            <div class="ex1">
            <?php foreach($order as $row): ?>
              <p><?= $row ["order_name"] ?> (<?= $row ["order_quantity"] ?>)</p>
    
              <?php endforeach;?>
            </div>  
            <h6>Table <?= $row ["table_id"] ?></h6>
            <div class="d-grid gap-2">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="button">Finish</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you are getting the data from database with 20 id in the query. how you want to show the data with different can please explain a bit?

Answer (score -1):

replace this

```
$pesanan = query("SELECT order_name, order_quantity,table_id FROM `pesanan` WHERE transaction_id  = 20;");
```

to this
// put validation for the $_GET['id'] like is_number and max length

```
$pesanan = query("SELECT order_name, order_quantity,table_id FROM `pesanan` WHERE transaction_id  = ".$_GET['id'].";");
```

then try to access the your site using a parameter '?id=20',exemple:

```
localhost/myproject/index.php?id=20
```

Comment: Right idea in one sense, but please don't encourage people to use insecure code. Your example is wide open to SQL injection attacks.